# flash with recaptcha or any other captcha solution

Tags: flash, actionscript, captcha, recaptcha

I have been looking over the internet for a while about this, but it doesn't seem like there is any information available specifically related to captcah and flash.

My purpose is to create an image up-loader on flash, and implement "recaptcha" on it, so the upload is controlled.

I know that some people will say, "well you can't automatize flash input so you don't need captcha in this situation" even though this is somewhat true, there is still screen macro programs that could potentially make the computer upload hundreds of pictures if there is not something in place to avoid it.

I thought of implementing my own captcha but that seems to me like i would be reinventing the wheel, can anyone point me on the right track for this? or suggest another approach to avoid abuse on my image up-loader flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's no support from reCaptcha for Flash, but someone hacked it parsing the returned HTML and then the generated image is shown to the user using Flash. See:

http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/e22d7e3c91bcc9db

Comment: Very interesting, i was about to start something like that but as the author of that message i am worry about the problems on the html interface changing. I guess it's a risk i will take, recaptcha has the best image captcha i has seen so ill go for it. Thanks a lot :), if i do find another solution ill make sure to post here for future reference.